# load two CROPIT.js instances with one file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a plugin [cropitjs](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit) to crop the user selected image. I want the user to select the image file via the file input ONCE, and the two cropit instances to load the same image.

I have tried with jquery clone of the file input, but was unable to load it to the preview.

**You can view the hosted preview of this [here](http://vaahaka.online/t)**

Right now, the file input prompts twice, and if i select the file twice the two cropit instances loads the image. I would like to be able to use one file input to load the two crop instances "image-editor1" and "image-editor2" as shown in the HTML markup.

NOTE: The end result is to crop the same image to two different sizes.

**Here is my HTML**

```
<!-- COVER IMAGE -->
<div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">

    <div class="image-editor1">
        <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" id="cropimg">
          <div class="select-image-btn">
            <label for="file" class="sr-only"><i class="ion-ios-camera-outline genicon"></i>ކަވަރ ފޮޓޯ އެއް އަޕްލޯޑް ކުރަށްވާ</label>
          </div>
        <div class="cropit-preview"></div>

        <div class="zoomcl">
            <i class="ion-image zoom2"></i>
            <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
            <i class="ion-image zoom1"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="filename"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="imgdata" class="imgdata" />

    </div>

 </div>

 <!-- MOBILE COVER IMAGE -->
 <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">

    <div class="image-editor2" id='imgedit1'>
        <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">

        <div class="select-image-btn">
            <label for="file" class="sr-only"><i class="ion-ios-camera-outline genicon"></i>ކަވަރ ފޮޓޯ އެއް އަޕްލޯޑް ކުރަށްވާ</label>
          </div>

        <div class="cropit-preview"></div>

        <div class="zoomcl">
            <i class="ion-image zoom2"></i>
            <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
            <i class="ion-image zoom1"></i>
        </div>   
        <input type="hidden" name="imgdata" class="imgdata" />

    </div>

 </div>
```

**Here is the JS**

```
 $('.select-image-btn').click(function() {

        $('.cropit-image-input').click();

        $('.image-editor1').cropit({
            imageBackground: true,
            imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 15,
            exportZoom: 4
        });

        $('.image-editor2').cropit({
            imageBackground: true,
            imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 15,
            exportZoom: 4

        });
    });
```

Thank you in advance for your help. :)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example please?

Comment: hi @Kiwad you can check the live preview at http://vaahaka.online/t

Comment: English please. Most of us cant read urdu/arabic.

Comment: As, to answer the question, save the image to a temporary file on the server and set both the `cropit-preview-image` class's `src` to that temporary file. Thats the easiest way. http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/